# How to make Date dimension common to fact and another dimension

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to design a star schema for an analytical project. This analytics revolves around "customer" dimension.

I'm having a hard time modelling the tables. These are the two tables I've come up with:

[image: ER]

I'll ask my concerns one-by-one:

1. How can I create date dimension so that it's common to fact(invoice_date) and customer(date_of_joining)? I mean, the end-user can have select a date so that he can see how many users got joined on that particular date as well as the total sales amount?
2. Is this a good design? I mean the "location", "cashier", and "category" can be called dimensions, but I'm flushing their "name" instead of their "id"s to the fact table. It's only for display purposes. So, I've a lesser number of dimension tables.

I'm entirely new to BI. So, an illustrative answers would be so much helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. It's the way I would do it, so it must be a good design.  I would call it dimCalendar, but that's minor stuff.
2. The way to do it is to create and populate the table, and then add foreign key references.

Answer (score 1):

You asked multiple questions, so I split the answer:

1. You can have a separate Calendar Date Dimension with Granularity of a Single Day. Depending on the kind of Reporting needed you can have the details corresponding to Week, Month, Year, Quarter etc. So you can have fields like `Date, Week_Start_Date, Week_End_Date, Month_Start_Date, Month_End_Date` etc. The best way to generate the calendar date dimension is with a spreadsheet and build it by hand. For some of the fields like Week_Start_Date, Week_End_Date, Month_Start_Date, Month_End_date you can use SQL. You many have some invalid dates in the Fact table. Foreign key references in fact tables referring to  special data conditions must point to a "non-date" date in the calendar date table. You need at least one of these special records in the calendar date table, but you may want to distinguish several of these unusual conditions. For the inapplicable date case, the value of the date type is inapplicable or NA. The foreign key in a fact table can never be null, as that violates referential integrity.
2. You may add the reference to date dimension to both Customer Dimension & Fact tables but if you need to see if you really need this, as you may join all the three tables (`Fact-> Date_dim on Date_key`, `Fact-> Cust_dim on Customer_id` & get the details you are looking for.)
3. You should assign proper name to the Fact table & Dimension Tables like Customer_Fact, Customer_Dim. Ideally there should be a separate Dimension table for each dimension (i.e. Location) with a Foreign key reference in Fact Table. This will help you track the changes in the Dimensions table as well as for any change in the dimension you may not need to load the entire fact.

Answer (score 0):

> This analytics revolves around "customer" dimension

No, the analysis should resolve around your fact tables

"fact" is a bad name for a fact table

What is the process or event that you want to analyze? That's your fact table

You date dimension should look like this:

```
create table dim.date (
  date_key int primary key,
  name text not null unique,
  date_iso date unique,
  year smallint,
  quarter smallint,
  month smallint,
  month_name text
  ...
);

insert into dim.date values 
(0, 'N/A', null, null, null, null, null),
(20180101, 'Jan 1, 2018', '2018-01-21', 2018, 1, 1, 'January');
```

Generally speaking you should avoid smart keys in a database, but dim.date is an exception. Use an int type for the primary key, but make its value represent the date (ex 20180101 for '2018-01-01'). This makes it easier to partition your fact tables by date in the future

Also, you don't need foreign keys in a data warehouse. Your ETL tool will handle referential integrity.

You should start with one big fact table that has all the columns you need for an analysis. If you need to save disk space, then split some data into dimensions

You should read [Agile Data Warehouse Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0956817203)

Comment: Big thanks for the book ref. What I want to do is that, since the "fact" table as well as the "customer" table has "date" attributes, I want to control/filter those records via a single date dimension. Is it okay to add the refs to fact as well as customer from the date dim?